# Node.js Https request Error

Tags: node.js, https

I've tried [the sample from the documentation](//nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) and it works great.

But when I change the URL to `https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/`, the request hangs. The only thing I get is:

```js
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Here's my code:

```js
var https = require('https');

this.dispatch = function(req, res) {
  var renderHtml = function(content) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(content, 'utf-8');
  }

  var parts = req.url.split('/');

  var options = {
    host: 'api.mercadolibre.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/sites/',
    method: 'GET'
  };

  var request = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
      process.stdout.write(d);
    });
  });

  request.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error('error');
    console.error(e);
  });

  request.end();
  return 'item id:' + parts[2];
};
```

I've tried with curl, soapui and with a browser. On all cases works great, but with node.js it doesn't.

How can I get more data on what's going on?

*added*

With curl i do: curl --sslv3 https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/ works.
I've test same in centos 6 and works too.
I've reinstalled node, this time from source, same problem. My Os is ubuntu 12.04. 
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to show us the you're using so we can diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about `api.mercadolibre.com` site, but I can call API if I remove `port` param, like following code:

```
var options = {
    host: 'api.mercadolibre.com',
    path: '/sites/',
    method: 'GET'
};
```

And we also need add param to support SSL version 3:

```
https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'SSLv3_method';
```

Comment: The `SSLv3_method` helped me solve a 2 year old problem! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a library like [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to deal with the details for you?

```js
var request = require('request');

request('https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/', {}, function(err, res, body) {
  console.log("Got body: ", body);
});
```

This yields:

```
Got body:  [{"id":"MLA","name":"Argentina"},{"id":"MLB","name":"Brasil"},{"id":"MCO","name":"Colombia"},{"id":"MCR","name":"Costa Rica"},{"id":"MEC","name":"Ecuador"},{"id":"MLC","name":"Chile"},{"id":"MLM","name":"Mexico"},{"id":"MLU","name":"Uruguay"},{"id":"MLV","name":"Venezuela"},{"id":"MPA","name":"Panamá"},{"id":"MPE","name":"Perú"},{"id":"MPT","name":"Portugal"},{"id":"MRD","name":"Dominicana"}]
```

Comment: Exact same thing. How can i get more data on whats going on?

Comment: When you say "Exact same thing," do you mean that you see `{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }` again? It sounds like they might be blocking access from your IP, or something.

Comment: yes exactly the same. I don't think in something blocking my ip, maybe something blocking node.js request. For now i'm exec curl inside node script  ( and works ) while i realize what happen. Is there a way to obtain more info on what's blocking my request?

Comment: using `request` worked well for me. just one more step. `body` printed my data as a string and I needed to convert it to json like this `JSON.parse(body)`

Answer (score 3):

Since it is working with curl, try using node-curl module. I lost a whole day trying to make it work in node.js with http and/or https modules until I switched to node-curl.

Try this:

```
var curl = require('node-curl');
curl('https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/', {SSLVERSION: 3}, function(err, res) {
    var body = res.body;
    res.close();
    console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Same here, working with curl but not with node.js.

Problem: here on CentOS-5 curl usesthe provides openssl libraries and so uses centos standard /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt for CA checks.

Where does node.js look for?, via strace there I cannot see any reference to a CA-file for checking.
Node.js request against server with valid SSL-certificate from well known old issuer are accepted, but not against my own webserver with own CA.
I put my own CA.crt in the ca-bundle.crt file, so now curl accepts it, but not node.js.

Only solution for now is to deactivate the verification-check for my dev-box:

```
    var client = require('https');
    var download_options = url.parse(sourceUrl);
    download_options.method = "GET";
    download_options.agent = false;
    download_options.rejectUnauthorized = false; / HERE to accept all SSL-certificates */

    var download_request = client.request(download_options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are behind a proxy which you need to specify to request. Proxy settings are detected automatically by libcurl, which node-curl uses. Therefore the request passes in node-curl.

Therefore, find out the proxy IP and port your organization uses, and try this:

```
var request = require('request');
request({
    uri : 'https://mail.google.com/mail',
    proxy : 'http://<proxy ip>:<proxy port>'
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
    }else{
        console.log(error);
        console.log(response.statusCode);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the ECONNRESET error if you do this:

```
post_options.path = 'history';
...
var req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
...
```

That is, you need to make sure your path has a <kbd>/</kbd> like this:

```
post_options.path = '/history';
...
```