# Node.js simple http request doesn't work

Tags: node.js, http

I wonder why such [simple http request](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) is not working...

```coffee
http = require("http")

url = "http://nodejs.org/"

console.log "Try a request to #{url}..."
reqHttp = http.request url, (response) ->

    console.log "Request to #{url}"
    response.on 'data', (chunk) -> console.log "chunk: ", chunk 

reqHttp.on 'error', (error) -> console.log "reqHttp error", error
```

After a minute or so it returns:

```coffee
reqHttp error { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

To make sure it is not a problem on my environment, I tried the `request` module and worked just fine:

```coffee
request = require("request")

url = "http://nodejs.org/"

request url, (error, response, body) ->
  console.log body if not error and response.statusCode is 200
```

It seems [I'm not the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771875/node-js-https-request-error).

So, I have a workaround for my problem (using `request` module), but I'd like to know why I can't use the buind-in http request. Is it buggy or unreliable? (Node.js version 0.8.21)

Comment: can you format your code, it is hard to make sense without any brackets

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that it's coffeescript. You can use http://coffeescript.org/#try: to see the js transcription. But basically, the functions scope is determined by relevant spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, this is really simple. You are constructing an `http request` but did not finish sending it. From the link you gave itself:

```
req.write('data\n');   //Write some data into request
req.write('data\n');
req.end();             //Finish sending request let request go. Please do this
```

Since you never used req.end(), it hung up since it never got completed. Node reset the inactive request

```
reqHttp error { [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

Comment: Thanks! Just put `req.end()` at the end of my code and it worked.
I think one could question the API design and all... either way, it's working. Thanks againg!